# Everytime Ubuntu boots, it creates a new mountpoint for my storage

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

[image: mount point 1, 2, 3... ect]

I created a ext4 partition from the terabyte hard drive on my dual-boot (windows10 - ubunutu18.04.01) laptop, with GParted: by first resizing the existing NTFS partition down from the left side then creating the etx4 in the empty space.

I've rebooted three times and now have three separate mount points.

If I reboot again I'll have another.

every application, such as steam, OBS and audacity configured to save to this drive will write to the latest one. file explore (Nautilus)

only shows one partition with the name "linuxStorage" and when opened, opens up the latest.

on my first boot files were written to the first, on my second boot files were written to the second.

contents are not shared. files that existed in the previous boot's partition are not present in the new boot's partition.

they behave like separate folders.

the old folders are not recognized as a hard drive by Ubuntu while the new one is.

the files for the old ones, as I understand, are physically written in my boot M2 SSD instead of on the partition in the terabyte HDD.

why is this happening and how do I stop this?

Comment: I'd suggest creating an entry in `/etc/fstab` (your file system table) for the drive, and have it always mount to a specific directory.  When mounted, the drive shadows (or hides) the real directory it's mounted to. If it's being mounted to a different directory, the old-folders you mentioned are just directories and files go on the / partition or drive.

Comment: how would you go about doing that? I've saved the contents of the partition to another folder so now if the manipulations require destroying it, I can afford that. I'd like to also clear out the fake partitions, will deleting the contents of `/media/$USER` suffice?

Comment: Where you mount is up to you, for my own things I mount in directories in / (eg. /de2900) as it's easy to type & that name means something to me. A common directory is also within /mnt/ but it's up to you (I think of /media/ as auto-mounted things so I'd not use it, but you can if you wish).   I'd use `blkid` to get the UUID's to add to fstab, but have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions  and use your existing mounts (compare info provided by blkid with what you see in your fstab as a guide). Only worry about cleaning up once you've got your mount working.

Comment: ok i'll try this and use /mnt and then delete the contents of /media. any idea *why* this was happening?